# Payment IPN failed at Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento-1.8, php, paypal

I have tested to placed some order using Paypal Standard but order status still show Pending Payment but our Sandbox Paypal account is received money. We also turn on ipn notification.

- Our URL: http://www.domain.com
- our SSL URL: https://domain.com

Turn ON Notification URL (Paypal Account): http://www.domain.com/default/paypal/ipn/

Our Merchant Platform : Magento ver 1.8.1.0

Which source files should i check and update IPN Url?

I have found so many questions related to this no clue work for me. Please Help !!

Answer (score 0):

This extension should solve your issue:

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mage-paypal-ipn-notification-alerts.html
```

Be sure to alter your Paypal IPN URL afterwards as the extension instructs.